# jQuery - selectors and $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok this is a general question about how to solve this issue, not to find some work around for the example given.

Lets say I have a `$(this)` object and it is a `select`, if I want to select the selected option and I had an `id` I could just bust a

`$('#id option:selected')`

game over.

but with a `this` I can't go `$(this+' option:selected')` or anything like that.

I am not so concerned with selecting the `option:selected` in the example so I don't want to know a workaround solution for this instance.

What I want to know is in general how you combine the subselectors like `:has` or `option:selected` with a `$(this)` situation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By using [the optional context parameter](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#expressioncontext):

```
$('option:selected', this)
```

Comment: Ah yes. I tend to forget about the second context parameter :)

Comment: jQuery( expression, [context] )

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: @Shog9: Holy. You can *edit* my answer? You're making me look good. Thanks.

Comment: Rack up the reputation points and you gain extra powers on SO.

Answer (score 2):

you could also do:

```
$(this).find('option:selected');
```